# How to checkout git repo without commits following me

Tags: git, svn, github

I am new to git and adjusting my workflow from SVN. The biggest problem I have is if I want to make a pull request into the master repo controlled by the project maintainer I have all these commits that I don't want.

here is the steps I've been taking

```
git checkout develop
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/develop
```

Modify file

```
git add /file
git commit file -m "some commit"
git push origin develop
```

Then on github make the pull request. Now when I make a pull request rather than it saying 1 commit 1 file its like 24 commits and has all these other people's commits from upstream. What additional steps do I need to add or remove from my workflow that will allow me to just submit a pull request for the one file I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this workflow instead:

1. `git fetch upstream`
2. `git checkout -b new_branch upstream/develop` (creates a new branch and puts you on it)
3. Modify the files you want to change.
4. `git add <files>`
5. `git commit -m "some message"`
6. `git push origin new_branch`

Also, is the upstream's main branch the `develop` branch? Usually the main branch is named `master`. If you're basing your changes off a branch other than the main branch, pull requests might show any commits that are in the other branch but not the main one.

Comment: the upstream has two branches develop and master

Comment: Okay, that's probably your issue then - by default, pull requests are compared against `master`, not another branch. Thus, since `develop` is probably ahead of `master` by a fair number of commits, those commits are showing up as part of the pull request (since by basing your changes on `develop`, you're effectively asking for those commits to be present before yours).

Comment: following the steps you provided work perfectly I am sending my pull requests into upstream/develop